# nextjs - Utilise Error.tsx to show custom error content

Tags: reactjs, next.js, error-handling, react-server-components

How can I leverage error.tsx to display custom error messages depending on the kind of error happened in the server?

During production the actual error message is stripped out and replaced with a generic error messaging.
I find this makes it difficult to use error.tsx to show custom error content

---

For example, code blocks below don't  work in production because next says:

- **During production, the `Error` object forwarded to the client only includes a generic `message` and `digest` property.** - This means below example won't work in production
- **During development, the `Error` object forwarded to the client will be serialized and include the `message` of the original error for easier debugging.** -  this means below example works only during development

---

- page.tsx - app/dashboard/page.tsx

```
export default async function Page() {
    const { data } = await getUsers();

    return (
        //List of users
    );
}
```

- error.tsx - app/dashboard/error.tsx

```
'use client';

export default function Error({ error, reset }: { error: Error & { digest?: string }; reset: () => void }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {error.message === 'UNAUTHORIZED' ? (
                <>
                    <h1>UNAUTHORIZED</h1>
                    <button onClick={reset}>Try again !!!</button>
                </>
            ) : error.message === 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR' ? (
                <>
                    <h1>UNAUTHORIZED</h1>
                    <button onClick={reset}>Try again !!!</button>
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <h1>Ooops</h1>
                    <h1>Something went wrong!!!</h1>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

If server action`getUsers()` results in errors like  **`UNAUTHORIZED (401)`**, or **INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR (500)** I expect error.tsx to render the right content. In development it works fine, but in production it would always render the last block.

What am I missing?
Am i wrong for thinking this is the way it should be handled?
How can i go about showing the right error to the user in the UI